# how to set selected value to state using react-semantic-ui

Tags: reactjs, react-select, semantic-ui-react

I was trying to set the value selected to react state but I end up get undefined. I have two inputs elements, the title input works just fine but I just can't figure out what I am missing with semantic ui's select element.

Here is my component's code:

```
const options = [
  { key: 'a', text: 'All', value: 'ALL' },
  { key: 'b', text: 'Branch', value: 'BRANCH' },
]

export function AddCategory({ eId }) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
  const [eligible, setEligible] = useState('')

  return <Mutation mutation={ADD_CATEGORY}
                   refetchQueries={[{ query: CATEGORIES_QUERY, variables: { eId } }]}>
    {(mutate, { loading, data, error }) => {
      if (error) return <ErrorMessage message={error.message}/>
      if (data) setTitle('')

      return <Form
        loading={loading}
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault()
          console.log('eligible', eligible) //undefined here

          mutate({
            variables: {
              input: {
                title,
                eligible,
                eId,
              },
            },
          })
        }}>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Input
            name="title"
            placeholder='Title'
            onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          />
          <Form.Field
            name="eligible"
            control={Select}
            options={options}
            placeholder='Select Eligibility'
            onChange={e => {
              console.log('target', e.target.value) //undefined here
              setEligible(e.target.value)
            }}
          />
          <Form.Button content='Add'/>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    }}
  </Mutation>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to try

```js
...
const onSelectChange = (evt, data) => {
    console.log( data.value);
}
...
onChange={onSelectChange},
...
```

Comment: I know using this way in class based component, but no idea in functional based with state hook, but I will try it.